# Center background slideshow autofit maintain aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

Trying to get a website background slideshow to center to the page - centering horizontally would be ok. Centering completely, maintaining aspect ratio, and autofitting would be amazing.

My coding capabilities are primitive so I have been piecing together templates and slideshow coding that I have been able to find. Currently the slideshow plays just fine behind my graphics and buttons, however it is aligned to the left and the best I can figure is the following...

HTML (the portion in question)

```
<div class="fadein"> <img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""> <img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""> <img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""> <img src="images/4.jpg" alt=""> <img src="images/5.jpg" alt=""> </div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                         .next('img')
                         .fadeIn()
                         .end()
                         .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 6000); // 6 seconds
});
  </script>
```

CSS

```
.fadein
{
     position: relative;
     width: 320px;
     height: 320px;
}

.fadein img
{
     position: fixed;
     width: auto;
     height: 100%;
     z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: maintaining aspect ratio of the images? you have a fixed size right now, is that how you want it?

Comment: It's not fixed size itself, the .fadein img has 100% height and auto width. Ideally it would center to the page and autosize, it's ok if the edges of the image are off the page.

Comment: if that's not possible, I'll take horizontal centering ;)

Comment: So we can disregard the 320px? and you want the images to fill 100% of the window?

Comment: right, that seems to be within the slideshow code, but it's the other part that tells the images how to take up space.

Answer (score 0):

```
.fadein{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.fadein img{
  min-width:320px;
  min-height:320px;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

This should, in theory center the image and have it scale to any size, to a max point of the width/height hitting the edge of the screen. You can remove the max width and height to prevent that though.

To enable vertical centering you may need a bit of js.

```
$('.fadein img').css({
   'margin-top':($('.fadein').height()-$('.fadein img').height())/2
});
```

*Note: I am unsure of how your slideshow works, this is just an example assuming .fadein img is the only image that will have that class and image within. You will have to adjust it to your setup.*

Comment: You are right that it's the only image with the fadein class. This has not resolved the issue for me, unfortunately. I will keep on it.

Comment: With just the css it should center horizontally, is it at least doing that? (you may have to re-add your z-index)